# Task is not breakable across pages

Tags: enumitem, tasks

The MWE is simple as it is but the problem occurs when it has to span across pages. Please see the picture. [image]

All Tasks items go together.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amssymb,tasks,enumitem}
 \begin{document}
   \begin{enumerate}
  \item hi
  \begin{tasks}(3)
   \task a \task b 
    \end{tasks}
   \end{enumerate}
   \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LaTeX wants to keep lists on the same page so it will break the page before the list rather than within the list.

`tasks` *will break* across pages if there won't be enough glue for vertical spacing  etc (see chapter 3.1 in `tasks` manual): https://i.stack.imgur.com/647s3.png

I would rather try to keep the `item` and the list on the same page. Add this to your preamble and see if it works for you:

```
\makeatletter
\@beginparpenalty=10000
\makeatother
```